# Number of executions for this while loop?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I'm not so sure about the  i = i * 2 part. Here's the code:

```
t = 0

i = 1

while i <= n:

    t = t + 1

    i = i * 2
```

How many times will this loop get executed? Thanks

Edit: n is any integer greater than 0

Comment: The given loop will be execute never at all. You are missing a definition of `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will be executed `log n` number of times (this is `log` with base 2).

In each iteration the value of `i` doubles until it's greater than `n`. This is a typical pattern in `log n` functions. Or to put it differently: if the size of `n` doubles then the loop is only executed one additional time.

Comment: i think its log base 2 specifically

Comment: @pyStarter the value of `n` is not relevant for complexity analysis. What matters is looking at what happens when `n` becomes bigger or smaller.

Comment: @geek_guy yes indeed, I have clarified it.